# Calling attribute accessor methods from within the class

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get call one of my classes attribute writers, but for some reason it never gets called. Here's some code that'll make this clearer:

```
class Test
  attr_reader :test

  def test=(val)
    puts 'Called'
    @test = val
  end

  def set_it(val)
    test = val
  end
end

obj = Test.new
obj.set_it 5
puts obj.test
=> nil
```

The puts statement at the end outputs 'nil'. Adding a debugging statement to test= shows it is never called. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I re-wrote this question partially, as I didn't truly understand the problem when I wrote it. So the question is much more generalized now.

Comment: fyi, you can generate those getters/setters using `attr_accessor :test`

Comment: I know, this was just an example. In the code I was working with the getter and setter do more work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing nothing "wrong" per se. Ruby just thinks you intend to set the local variable test to val, not call the `test=` method. `self.test = val` will do what you expect.

Comment: I thought it was something like that. I tried test=(val) thinking that may convince Ruby I'm trying to call a method. Thanks!

Comment: So this would be true whether a mixin is involved or not? If there's no receiver specified Ruby assumes you're setting a local variable? Makes sense.

Comment: Ahh, principle of least surprise can be surprising if you're coming from a language that handles this differently ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some other resources on this (apparently common) problem:

Another Stack Overflow question: [Why do ruby setters need “self.” qualification within the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715/why-do-ruby-setters-need-self-qualification-within-the-class)

From this [guys's blog](http://macournoyer.com/blog/2009/01/14/to-self-or-not-to-self/):

> As a Ruby newbie you probably once did `race = "hooman"` but noticed it didn’t work and said to yourself: “I won’t let this happen to me again. From now on, I’ll prepend `self.` whenever I’m calling a method!”