# When to use self in Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, self

Question: when do I need to use self in my models in Rails?

I have a `set` method in one of my models.

```
class SomeData < ActiveRecord::Base
  def set_active_flag(val)
    self.active_flag = val
    self.save!
  end
end
```

When I do this, everything works fine. However, when I do this:

```
class SomeData < ActiveRecord::Base
  def set_active_flag(val)
    active_flag = val
    save!
  end
end
```

The active_flag value doesn't change, rather it fails silently. Can someone explain?

I can't find any duplicates, but if someone finds one that's fine too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use 'self' in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252031/when-to-use-self-in-ruby)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

When you're doing an action on the instance that's calling the method, you use self.

With this code

```
class SocialData < ActiveRecord::Base
  def set_active_flag(val)
    active_flag = val
    save!
  end
end
```

You are defining a brand new scoped local variable called active_flag, setting it to the passed in value, it's not associated with anything, so it's promptly thrown away when the method ends like it never existed.

```
self.active_flag = val
```

However tells the instance to modify its own attribute called active_flag, instead of a brand new variable. That's why it works.

Comment: "When you're doing an action on the instance that's calling the method, you use self." That's not quite accurate. Calling a (non-setter) method on the current object works just fine without `self`. So does setting instance variables (directly) - in fact you can't do that using `self` (without reflection anyway).

Comment: How odd that it wouldn't reference the instance variable... another difference from Java. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @varatis: Since variables aren't declared in ruby, the only way to create a variable is to assign something to it. Java can tell whether `foo = bar` is assigning to a local variable or an instance variable, because it can just look whether a local variable with that name has been declared. Ruby can't do that because there are no declarations. You could say "call the setter method if one exists - otherwise create a local variable", but then you run into trouble with `method_missing`. Also note that `self.foo = bar` calls a method named `foo=`, it doesn't (directly) set an instance variable.

Comment: @varatis Also, instance variables are `@var_name`.

Comment: could anyone explain why

Answer (score 78):

This happens because of scoping. When you're inside of a method and you try to **set** a new variable like this:

```
class SomeData < ActiveRecord::Base
  def set_active_flag(val)
    active_flag = val
  end
end
```

You are creating a brand new variable that lives inside of set_active_flag. As soon as that's done executing, it goes away, not altering `self.active_flag` (the actual instance variable) in any way.

**HOWEVER** (this was a source of confusion for me): when you try to **read** an instance variable in ruby, like this:

```
class SomeData < ActiveRecord::Base
  def whats_my_active_flag
    puts active_flag
  end
end
```

You'll actually get `self.active_flag` (the actual instance variable) returned.

---

**Here's why:**

Ruby will do what it can to avoid returning `nil`.

1. It initially asks "does `active_flag` exist within the scope of `whats_my_active_flag`?
2. It searches and realizes the answer is "nope", so it jumps **up** one level, to the instance of SomeData
3. It asks the same thing again: "does `active_flag` exist within this scope?
4. The answer is "yup" and so it says "I got something for ya" and it returns that!

However, if you define `active_flag` within the `whats_my_active_flag`, and then ask for it, it goes through the steps again:

1. It asks "does `active_flag` exist within the scope of `whats_my_active_flag`?
2. The answer is "yup", so it returns that value

In either case, it won't **change** the value of `self.active_flag` unless you explicitly tell it to.

An easy way to describe this behavior is "it doesn't want to disappoint you" and return `nil` -- so it does its best to find whatever it can.

At the same time, "it doesn't want to mess up data that you didn't intend to change" so it doesn't alter the instance variable itself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great explanation.  I've been searching for an hour trying to figure out why I need to use self for setting values but can jump to different methods and use what was seemingly a local variable for reads without using self

Comment: Great explanation! I was also confused by the difference when you *read* or *write* the variable

Comment: What's the purpose of doing this? Is this a bad language design?

Answer (score 2):

It's to make sure you're using the setter method and not scoping a new variable. It's a Ruby and AR usage detail that often trips people up (the other being the (mis-)use of an instance variable).

Note there's already [update_attributes!](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes!) although I understand the desire to abstract.

There's also [toggle!](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/toggle!), which might be even nicer, depending on your interface to the flag.

Comment: I might be having a dangling modifier problem here... are you saying that the fact that "foo = bar" creates a local variable is an *AR* implementation detail?

Comment: @sepp2k That wouldn't really make any sense, but my edit wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

When use `active_flag = val` ruby thought your are define a local variable, the best way is `self.active_flag = val`, if you got it, hope you  know that `send(:active_flag=, val)` will works too.