# Why do I need to use self when assigning values in my Rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a class in Rails:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  def update_status
    return if status == 'sold'
    return unless reserved_until.nil? || reserved_until.past?
    self.status = 'open'
  end
end
```

where `status` and `reserved_until` are fields in the database for the `Ticket` model, why do I only have to use `self` when I am assigning a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you do `status = 'open'` you are creating a new local variable called `status`. That's not about Rails. That is about how Ruby interpreter evaluate your code.

Comment: Oooh, okay that makes total sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer here explains it pretty well. -> [When to use self in Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805136/when-to-use-self-in-model)

To read further in depth this is an excellent blog that puts it clearly. http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to invoke a setter method on self, you have to write self.status = "open". If you just write status = "open", the ruby parser recognizes that as a variable assignment and thinks of status as a local variable from now on. For the parser to realize, that you want to invoke a setter method, and not assign a local variable, you have to write obj.status = "open", so if the object is self, self.status = "open"