# Class variable using attr_accessor inside class << self

Tags: ruby, class-variables, attr-accessor

Can someone explain why self.foo= works outside of the class << self, while foo= does not work within the class << self.

```
class A
  class << self
    attr_accessor :foo
    foo = 'foo'
  end
end

p A.foo # => "nil"

class A
  class << self
    attr_accessor :foo
  end
  self.foo = 'foo'
end

p A.foo # => "foo"
```

This is not the same question as [When to use 'self' in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252031/when-to-use-self-in-ruby/1252043)

To be clear, I am not asking when to use self. I am asking why I cannot set the class variable inside a 'class << self' block, but I can outside of it.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252031/when-to-use-self-in-ruby/1252043#1252043

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your second example isn't a class variable, it's a class instance variable to this class the proof is that if you inherited like this you'll get nil

```
class A
  class << self
    attr_accessor :foo
  end
  self.foo = 'foo'
end

class B < A
end

B.foo # => nil
```

So if you want to add a class variable in `class << self` you can use `@@`

```
class A

  class << self
  @@foo = :foo
    def foo
      @@foo
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The reason I want to use attr_accessor is because I want the subclasses to have different values for foo. Whereas this was, if I change foo within a subclass it would also change the value of A.foo

Comment: So you really mean it to be a class instance variable, right ?

Comment: hmmm I guess so. Sounds a bit funny to say that, but it does get the job done.