# local methods act differently when called with/without self. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have model called `User` with a `has_many` relationship to `UserFilter`. `UserFilter` has a `belongs`_to relationship to `User`.

Within the User model I have a method called `update_user_filters(filter_params_array)`

This method modifies `user_filters` like something like this

```
def update_user_filters(filter_params_array)
  new_filters = []
  old_filter = user_filters 

  filters_params_array.each do |filter_params|
    if filter_params[:id].blank? #if the filter does not yet exist
      new_filters << UserFilter.new(filter_params)
    end
  end
  user_filters = new_filters
end
```

This sets the `user_filters` to the expected value but upon saving it does not update the `user_filters` in the db.

however if I change the assignment to the following it does. Can someone explain why this is?

```
self.user_filters = new_filters
```

Note that when I first refer to `user_filters` in the model is does a select in the db so I am not sure how this local method is working differently with `self` and without `self`

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715/why-do-ruby-setters-need-self-qualification-within-the-class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`user_filters` just creates a local variable. `self.user_filters` assigns it to the object. you probably want `@user_filters = ...`.

Comment: So I am a little confused then. If user_filters and user_filters= are dynamically defined by active record will they not just work as methods? so calling user_filters I does actually call the method since I do not set it and it returns the records when called. 

Similarly I would expect user_filters= to call the method generated by active record also. 

But I guess what you are saying is that it is just creating a local variable? But how does user_filters have values if it is just a alocal variable. Note I have updated the code above to be more clear

Comment: old_filters above now has an array list of filters so it seems that user_filters is not local. But yet when I call it the end it does act like a local variable per your previous comments

Comment: This is a common point of confusion with Ruby. See, the Ruby interpreter does not know if "user_filters =" is setting a local variable or calling a method - so it does the former. This is why you need "self.user_filters =" to ensure it calls the method, not sets a local variable.

Comment: here is a fairly detailed explanation http://www.rubyfleebie.com/use-self-explicitly/