# In Ruby, if we define a method call "c=", why can't it be invoked by c = 3?

Tags: ruby

For example, if we

```
def c=(foo)
  p "hello"
end

c = 3
c=(3)
```

and no "hello" will be printed.  I know it can be invoked by `self.c = 3` but why?  and in what other ways can it be invoked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do ruby setters need "self." qualification within the class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715/why-do-ruby-setters-need-self-qualification-within-the-class)

Answer (score 8):

`c = 3` (and `c = (3)`, which is completely equivalent to it) is always interpreted as a local variable assignment. You might say it should be interpreted as a local variable assignment only if a method `c=` is not defined on self, but there are various problems with that:

1. At least MRI needs to know at parse time which local variables are defined in a given scope. However it is not known at parse time, whether a given method is defined or not. So ruby couldn't know whether `c = 3` defines the variable `c` or calls the method `c=` until runtime, which means it wouldn't know whether a local variable `c` is defined at parse time. This means that MRI would need to change the way it handles local variables in the parser, to make it work like you want it to.
2. It wouldn't be possible to define a local variable named `c` if a method is `c=` is already defined. You might say that's okay, because having local variables and methods with the same name is confusing anyway. However consider the case, where you define `method_missing` so that `foo=` is defined for every possible foo (as is the case on `OpenStruct`s for example). In that case it would not be possible to define local variables at all.
3. You can't tell for sure, whether an object responds to `c=` without running it because it might be handled by `method_missing`. So the whole thing would actually be undecidable.

Comment: +1 for giving a comprehensive list of why's (whereas I provided only the behavior/rule itself).

Answer (score 7):

Because local variables take precedence over previously defined methods/variables with the same name.  You need to qualify with 'self' in this case so that c isn't interpreted to be the declaration/assignment of a local variable.

Comment: The code he posted was sufficient. If you did `self.c = 3`, it'd work in IRB.

Comment: On a side note, people should be voting for sepp2k's answer.  It's better and more complete than mine is.

Answer (score 3):

The Ruby only calls this kind of method if the code cannot be interpreted as a variable assignment. There is no better way to force the method call.

```
self.c = 1
send(:c=, 1)
__send__(:c=, 1)
method(:c=).call(1)
method(:c=)[1]
```