# Aliasing Setter Methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby, alias

Aliasing methods in Ruby is relatively straight-forward. A contrived example:

```
class Person
  def name
    puts "Roger"
  end
end

class User < Person
  alias :old_name :name
  def name
    old_name
    puts "Staubach"
  end
end
```

In this case, running `User.new.name` will output:

```
Roger
Staubach
```

That works as expected. However, I'm trying to alias a setter method, which is apparently not straight-forward:

```
class Person
  def name=(whatever)
    puts whatever
  end
end

class User < Person
  alias :old_name= :name=
  def name=(whatever)
    puts whatever
    old_name = whatever
  end
end
```

With this, calling `User.new.name = "Roger"` will output:

```
Roger
```

It appears that the new aliased method gets called, but the original does not.

What is up with that?

ps - I know about `super` and let's just say for the sake of brevity that I do not want to use it here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think Ruby will recognize `old_name = whatever` as a method call when it lacks an object reference. Try:

```
def name=(whatever)
  puts whatever
  self.old_name = whatever
end
```

instead (note the `self.`)

Comment: Thanks, that works. I also realized that there is pretty much no reason that the aliased version has to be a setter, I can just pass the parameter directly to it and it'll work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715/why-do-ruby-setters-need-self-qualification-within-the-class

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
alias old_name= name=
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `self.old_name = whatever`, just plain `old_name` is a local.

Answer (score -1):

Does the alias *have* to be a setter?

```
class User < Person
  alias :old_name :name=
  def name=(whatever)
    old_name whatever
  end
end
```