# Why aren't these methods resolving?

Tags: ruby

Given this code:

```
class Something
  attr_accessor :my_variable

  def initialize
    @my_variable = 0
  end

  def foo
    my_variable = my_variable + 3
  end
end

s = Something.new
s.foo
```

I get this error:

```
test.rb:9:in `foo': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from test.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

If `attr_accessor` creates a method called `my_variable` (and ..=), why can't `foo` find the method? It works if I change it to `self.my_variable`, but why? Isn't `self` the default receiver?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not calling the method there, you're actually referencing the same variable you're in the process of defining! This is a little gotcha in Ruby.

What would be better is if you referenced and set the instance variable instead:

```
@my_variable = @my_variable + 3
```

Or shorter:

```
@my_variable += 3
```

Or you could call the setter method, as you found (and [Jits pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172017/why-arent-these-methods-resolving/6172032#6172032)) out:

```
self.my_variable += 3
```

This last one will call the `my_variable=` method defined by the `attr_accessor`, where the other two will only modify a variable. If you did it this way, you could override `my_variable=` to do something different to the value passed in:

```
def my_variable=(value)
  # do something here
  @my_variable = value
end
```

**BONUS**

Or you could call the method explicitly by passing an empty set of arguments through:

```
my_variable = my_variable() + 3
```

This is not "The Ruby Way" to go about it, but it's still interesting to know that you can still call a method this way if you have a local variable of the same name.

Comment: WRT the Bonus: You'd still need to either set the ivar directly or use the setter. That just sets a local.

Answer (score 5):

```
my_variable = my_variable + 3
```

... is a local variable assignment, which takes precedence.

Hence the need for `self` - in order to scope it to the object.

Answer (score 3):

If you do `my_variable` in `foo`, that's assigning to the *local variable* `my_variable`, not calling the method `my_variable=`.

To assign the value as you desire, you do need to use `self` as you found out.

See also this question: [Why do ruby setters need “self.” qualification within the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715/why-do-ruby-setters-need-self-qualification-within-the-class)

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case the scope of the variable is only within the function, unless you prepend it with `self.` of `@`.