# Rails model variable changing unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

Going mad here.  Any pointers gratefully received!

I've got a Delivery model and I'm trying to add a method to update the delivery state, based on delivery lines.  This function is defined within the model class, and delivery_state is one of the model attributes:

```
def updateDeliveryState
  expectedLines = DeliveryLine.where( :delivery_id => id,
                                      :line_state => 'EXPECTED' )
  logger.debug "State1: #{delivery_state}"

  if expectedLines.length == 0
    if delivery_state == 'EXPECTED' || delivery_state == 'RECEIVING'
      delivery_state = 'RECEIVED'               # commenting this line fixes it
      save
    end
  else
    logger.debug "State2: #{delivery_state}"
    if delivery_state == 'EXPECTED'
      logger.debug "Updating to receiving"
      delivery_state = 'RECEIVING'
      save
    end
  end
end
```

What I'm seeing in the log is that between the 2 `logger.debug` lines, the delivery_state has been cleared:

```
State1: EXPECTED
DeliveryLine Load (4.5ms)  SELECT "delivery_lines".* FROM "delivery_lines" 
WHERE "delivery_lines"."line_state" = 'EXPECTED' 
AND "delivery_lines"."delivery_id" = 227
State2:
```

If I comment out the line marked in the above code, it appears to work OK:

```
State1: EXPECTED
DeliveryLine Load (9.6ms)  SELECT "delivery_lines".* FROM "delivery_lines" 
WHERE "delivery_lines"."line_state" = 'EXPECTED' 
AND "delivery_lines"."delivery_id" = 227
State2: EXPECTED
Updating to receiving
```

However, I can see after refreshing that the delivery is still EXPECTED after this??

Comment: Can you try `self.delivery_state = 'RECEIVED'` inside the first `if` to make sure you are not creating a local variable and are calling the setter instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment: it seems like you are creating a local variable in the `if`. Look:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar

  def test
    unless bar
      bar = 1
    end
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.test
puts f.bar # empty line, bar is nil
```

Now let's make sure we call the setter:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar

  def test
    unless bar
      self.bar = 1
    end
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.test
puts f.bar # prints 1
```

See: [Why do ruby setters need “self.” qualification within the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715/why-do-ruby-setters-need-self-qualification-within-the-class)

Comment: Thankyou!  Got it working and thanks especially for the link explaining what is going on!.  I had originally written this code in the controller, and so I knew it should work, but didn't realise what I broke.

Answer (score 0):

can you try to use `save(:validate => false)` ?

Sometimes Rails has this nasty habit of silently failing validations and not saving.

You probably want to save your state no matter what... :)

Comment: He does have a bug in his code - it's pretty obvious - so why the downvvote?

Comment: I agree, your answer is correct - I guess I never ran into that one, because I always explicitly write self.