# Self stands for? Ruby

Tags: ruby

just encountered the following code in RoR 3.2.8. Does that mean that self belongs to the merge function or to the class?

```
results.merge(
        profile: self)
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do Ruby setters need "self." qualification within the class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715/why-do-ruby-setters-need-self-qualification-within-the-class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on the context. ie. where you found this line of code.

```
class Profile
  def foo
    results.merge(profile: self)
  end
end

p = Profile.new
p.foo
```

In this case "self" will be referring to the object "p", which is the current object in the context where "self" is used.

Answer (score 3):

it's merging current object - profile to results

http://jimmycuadra.com/posts/self-in-ruby