# Rails after_initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following class:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :choices
  attr_accessible :content, :choices, :answer_id

  after_initialize :after_initialize

  private
    def after_initialize
      choices ||= ['','','','']
    end
end
```

The intent is that each question has 4 possible answer choices, and I want the question objects to always have those choices initialized, even if they are blank.  They should never be saved to the database blank, but that's a separate issue.  Anyway...

In my question form, I iterate through the choices:

```
  <% @question.choices.each_with_index do |value, key| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= f.radio_button :answer_id, key %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="question[choices][]" type="text" value="<%= value %>" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

This should give the user 4 inputs to enter the answer choice text and radio buttons to choose which one is correct.  When I load up the form to create a new question, I get this error:

```
undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass
```

So basically, the `:choices` attribute is not getting initialized correctly.  Indeed, inspecting `@question` gives me this:

```
#<Question id: nil, content: nil, choices: nil, answer_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I would expect everything else to be nil, but I'm expecting `:choices` to be `['','','','']`.  Am I timing this wrong?

Comment: try changing the name of your after_initialize function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. When setting an attribute the name isn't enough. Prefix with `self.` to make it work:

```
self.choices ||= ['','','','']
```

Using just `choices` creates a local variable of that name rather than setting the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The following code from `after_initialize` is updating the `choices` local variable, which is not what you want:

```
choices ||= ['','','','']
```

You need to use

```
self.choices || = ['','','','']
```

as discussed in [Why do Ruby setters need "self." qualification within the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715/why-do-ruby-setters-need-self-qualification-within-the-class)