# Update all props of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app has the following models

```
class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post

  def analyse!
    client = ThirdPartyService.new
    res = client.get_metrics post.body
    # how to update itself here with the result of res?
  end
end
```

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :metrics

  after_save :start_analysis

  private

  def start_analysis
    metric = create_metric
    metric.analysis!
  end
end
```

The Metric table has a bunch of metrics, like:

```
adverbs_percentage
sentiment
```

and the returning result of calling:

```
client = ThirdPartyService.new
res = client.get_metrics post.body
```

is a hash containing those exactly props:

```
{
  :adverbs_percentage => 10
  :sentiment => 'Positive'
}
```

I would like to know how can I update the Metric from the `analyse!` method, something like:

```
update_myself(res)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do:

```
class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post

  def analyse!
    client = ThirdPartyService.new
    res = client.get_metrics post.body
    update res
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Rails [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#update), you can update your model in the following way.

```rb
m = Metric.first
m.adverbs_percentage= 10
m.sentiment= 'Positive'
m.save
```

In the above example, `adverbs_percentage=`, `sentiment=`, `save` are instance method of `Metric` class.
You defined these instance methods by inheriting `ApplicationRecord`.

Since they are instance method, you can call these methods in your instance method(`analyse!`).

```rb
class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post

  def analyse!
    client = ThirdPartyService.new
    res = client.get_metrics post.body

    self.sentiment = res.sentiment
    self.adverbs_percentage = res.adverbs_percentage 
    save
  end
end
```

Note that `adverbs_percentage=` and `sentiment=` needs `self.`, because ruby need to distinguish them from local variable assignment.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715/why-do-ruby-setters-need-self-qualification-within-the-class) for more detail.